# Compare multiple dates on one table with multiple dates in another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using T-SQL in SSMS 2016. For a report, I want to compare two tables to see if the date ranges in table2 cover the date ranges in table1, then return the rows in table1 that are not fully covered by the date ranges in table2.

The number of entries in table1 and table2 will grow in number over time.

```
table1                              table2

id       start date  end_date       id      start date  end date
-----------------------------       ----------------------------
1001     01/08/17    31/08/17       1001    07/07/17    02/09/17
1001     01/10/17    31/10/17       1001    01/11/17    12/12/17
1001     01/11/17    30/11/17
1001     01/01/18    05/01/18
```

Comment: It may be worth while to look into Intersect and Except operators. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql

Comment: Not clear.  Need more explanation and desired output and why.  VTC

Comment: I understood your questions @intothewild, please try my queries I made for you below.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1 Query Answer**

```
-- Does Table2 cover the date ranges in table1?  Result is by each date in Table2.
DECLARE     @t1_minStartDate    DATE,
            @t1_maxEndDate      DATE

SELECT      @t1_minStartDate    = MIN(startDate),
            @t1_maxEndDate      = MAX(endDate)
FROM        table1

SELECT      startDate AS t2_startDate,
            CASE WHEN startDate < @t1_minStartDate THEN
                'Yes'
            ELSE
                'No'
            END AS t2_startDate_covers_all,
            endDate AS t2_endDate,
            CASE WHEN startDate > @t1_maxEndDate THEN
                'Yes'
            ELSE
                'No'
            END AS t2_endDate_covers_all
FROM        table2 t2
```

**Result:**

```
t2_startDate    t2_startDate_covers_all t2_endDate  t2_endDate_covers_all
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-07-07      Yes                     2017-09-02  No
2017-11-01      No                      2017-12-12  No
```

**Question 2 Query Answer**

```
-- Rows in Table1 that are not fully covered by the date ranges in table2
SELECT      t1.id,
            t1.startDate,
            t1.endDate
FROM        table1 t1
WHERE       NOT EXISTS (SELECT      1
                        FROM        table2 t2
                        WHERE       t1.startDate BETWEEN t2.startDate AND t2.endDate
                                AND t1.endDate   BETWEEN t2.startDate AND t2.endDate)
```

**Result:**

```
id      startDate       endDate
----------------------------------
2       2017-10-01      2017-10-31
4       2018-01-01      2018-01-05
```